# OpenMP C++ (trouble with compliling)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, openmp

I decided to calculate *e* as the sum of rows to get 2.718....
Well my code without OpenMP works perfectly and I measured the time which it is taking for calculations. When I used OpenMP to parralelize my calculation however, I got an error. I am running my program on core i7(8 cores 4 logic and  4 physical). As people say I must get a time twice as fast without using openMP. Below is my code:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <time.h>
  #include <math.h>
  #include "fact.h" 
  #include <cstdlib>;
  #include <conio.h>;
  using namespace std;
   int main()
  {
clock_t t1,t2;
int n;
long double exp=0;
long double y;
int p;
cout<<"Enter n:";
cin>>n;
t1=clock();
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2);
for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
{
p=i+1;
    exp=exp+(1/((fact(p))));
}
t2=clock();
double total_clock;
total_clock=t2-t1;
long double total_exp;
total_exp=exp+2;
cout<<total_clock<<"\n the time is used for parralel calculations"<<endl;
cout<<total_exp<<endl;

cin.get();
getch();
    return 0;
     }
```

**Fact() using function to calculate factorial of the number**

```
    long double fact(int N)

     {
    if(N < 0) 
      return 0; 
  if (N == 0) 
    return 1; 
   else 
    return N * fact(N - 1); 
    }
```

**Error 3   error C3005: ;: unexpected token in directive OpenMP "parallel for" c:\users\александр\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\openmp.cpp 18**

Comment: AFAIK VS requires special setup in order to use OpenMP.

Comment: I think that semi-colon should not exist.

Comment: Actually in this case the compiler error message is pretty clear and local to the error.

Answer (score 1):

When using openmp pragmas, semicolons are not needed, hence:

"#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2);"

should be "#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)"

without the ;

Comment: num_threads(4) should be a good start since you have 4 physical cores. You can try a greater thread number up to 8 since i7 processors support hyper threading. Just test it and compare the times. Also you should have care with your code:
I suggest you to use
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2) reduction(+ : exp)
All the threads are accessing a global variable (exp) without consider anything, what you want to do is to keep a local variable for each thread and add all of them at the end.
The reduction is a nice work around for this. https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#REDUCTION